# Diminishing weights for pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following **df**: visitor can make multiple visits, and the number of page views is recorded in each visit.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'visitor_id':[1,1,2,1],'visit_id':[1,2,1,3], 'page_views':[10,20,30,40]})


   page_views  visit_id  visitor_id
0          10         1           1
1          20         2           1
2          30         1           2
3          40         3           1
```

What I need is to create an additional column called weight, which will diminish with a certain parameter. For example, if this parameter is 1/2, the newest visit has a weight of 1, 2nd newest visit a weight of 1/2, 3rd is 1/4 and so on.

E.g. I want my dataframe to look like:

```
   page_views  visit_id            visitor_id   weight
0          10         1(oldest)           1       0.25
1          20         2                   1        0.5
2          30         1(newest)           2          1
3          40         3(newest)           1          1
```

Then I will be able to group using their weight e.g.

`df.groupby(['visitor_id']).Weight.sum()` to get weighted page views group by.

**Doesnt work as expected**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'visitor_id':[1,1,2,2,1,1],'visit_id':[5,6,1,2,7,8], 'page_views':[10,20,30,30,40,50]})
df['New']=df.groupby('visitor_id').visit_id.transform('max') - df.visit_id
df['weight'] = pd.Series([1/2]*len(df)).pow(df.New.values)
df

   page_views  visit_id  visitor_id  New  weight
0          10         5           1    3       0
1          20         6           1    2       0
2          30         1           2    1       0
3          30         2           2    0       1
4          40         7           1    1       0
5          50         8           1    0       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
df.groupby('visitor_id').visit_id.apply(lambda x : 1*1/2**(max(x)-x))
Out[1349]: 
0    0.25
1    0.50
2    1.00
3    1.00
Name: visit_id, dtype: float64
```

Maybe try this

```
df['New']=df.groupby('visitor_id').visit_id.transform('max')-df.visit_id
pd.Series([1/2]*len(df)).pow(df.New.values)
Out[45]: 
0    0.25
1    0.50
2    1.00
3    1.00
Name: New, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be exactly what I need

Comment: @GRS glad I can help , happy coding

Comment: I tried this code on something of the size of 300,000 rows and it seems to be super slow. Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: @GRS update, I change the calculation part outside groupby , this will save time :-)

Comment: @GRS right now, you only need to get the groupby max , then all other will outside the groupby

Comment: This works very fast but for some reason I'm getting different weight sum. Although, I can see how it's correct.

Comment: Even `np.power([1/2]*len(df), df.New.values)` gives me the same.

Comment: Okay, it works as expected if I use 0.5 instead of 1/2